# Image Positioning (Google Maps Android API v2)

Tags: java, android, image, google-maps, overlay

**Background information**

- Google Maps Android API v2 is being used
- image.png is illustrated below:

[image: Fig 1.0: An image where the grey oval represents a building structure and the light orange spaces are the corners]

**Question**

Vector graphics are not supported; therefore a setting the image as part of a GroundOverlay could work.

However, the `positionFromBounds()` method positions the image according to South West and North East bounds.

Thus, the building structure's location is incorrect because the corners of the image are used instead of the actual building representation.

How can I place the image more precisely on a map?

Comment: can you try using the center point of the object to map to the building representation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the centre point of the building. Nevertheless, I have collected latitude and longitude coordinates of the oustide.